# How to stop recursive function after some time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on this random stuff here. 
like a random Div hovering around. 
Now when mouse is hovered the function starts but how can I automatically stop the function called animateDiv() after some time. 
thanks.
here is the code.

**html code**

```
<div class="a">
    <button id="myButton">Click Me ;)</button>
</div>
```

and **jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').mouseenter(function() {
         animateDiv();

    });
});

function makeNewPosition() {      
   var h = $(window).height() - 50;
   var w = $(window).width() - 50;
   var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
   var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

   return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
   var newq = makeNewPosition();
   $('.a').animate( 
      {top: newq[0], 
       left: newq[1], }
      ,400, function () {
            animateDiv();
       });
    };
```

Comment: When do you want it to change?

Comment: set a global flag and check it on the step function you can pass to animate

Comment: write your code (animateDiv()) inside setTimeout() block

Comment: i want to change it after some seconds when the mouse is hovered over the button.

Comment: This looks like a bad implementation. the anonymous callback function for animate() needs to save its context, so it will stay in memory. its way better to use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here this will stop the animate function after two seconds. I have marked the changes I made with the comment '//new change'. You can control the time in milliseconds the animation runs using the setTimeOut function. I have used 2 seconds for example. You can also set this using a random generator to get different time spans.

```
var animate = false; //new change

$(function () {
    $('.a').mouseenter(function() {
        animate = true;//new change
        animateDiv();
        setTimeout(function(){animate = false },2000)//new change
    });
});

function makeNewPosition() {      
   var h = $(window).height() - 50;
   var w = $(window).width() - 50;
   var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
   var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

   return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
   var newq = makeNewPosition();
   console.log(newq);
    $('.a').animate( 
      {top: newq[0], 
       left: newq[1], }
      ,400, function () {
            if(animate) animateDiv();//new change
       });
    };
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Td39A/3/). Check the console log

Here is how this works. Before you begin animation in recursive function you set animation flag to true. The function calls itself only if this flag is true. Then you start a saperate timer which make animate flag false, which will cause the recursive function to break.

PS: The animation code in your original question doesn't work anyway. But i didn't try to debug it as your question was only about how to stop the function after a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a setTimeout to stop it.

```
setTimeout(function (){
    $('.a').stop();
}, "1000");
```

This will stop any animations present on any element with the class `a` after 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use some sort of variable to check if you want to animate or not.

```
var do_animation = true;
function animateDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.a').animate({
         top: newq[0],
         left: newq[1],
     }, 400, function () {
         if(do_animation) // The condition, if false this will not execute.
             animateDiv();
     });
};
```

And then when you want to stop it you just set `do_animation` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stop it, but rather to *not run it* after a while. Just put a condition in to decide if it needs to be run or not.

```
    $('.a').animate(
        { top: newq[0], left: newq[1], },400, function ()
        {
            // put a condition here
            if(Math.random() > .01){ // will stop after a while
                animateDiv();
            }

        });
```